# How to prove this integral result?

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Please help me to prove this :

$$\int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} (\tan x)^{n-1} dx= \frac{\pi}{2}\csc(\frac{n\pi}{2}), 0<n<2$$

I've tried using substitution t = tan x
But couldn't figure out what to do next.

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: Ok, go ahead.$\,$

Comment: Welcome to math.SE. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use $\beta$ integral
$$\int_{0}^{\pi/2} \sin^{n-1} x \cos^{1-n} d x=\frac{1}{2} \frac{\Gamma(n/2) \Gamma(1-n/2)}{\Gamma(1)}= \frac{1}{2}\frac{\pi}{\sin n \pi/2}.$$ if $1-n/2>0$$ \implies 0<n<2.$

Use $$\Gamma(z) \Gamma(1-z)=\frac{\pi}{\sin z\pi}$$
See:
[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20beta%20function,0%2C%20Re%20y%20%3E%200](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20beta%20function,0%2C%20Re%20y%20%3E%200).

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\tan^{n - 1}\pars{x}\,\dd x}
\,\,\,\stackrel{\tan\pars{x}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{n - 1} \over 1 + x^{2}}\,\dd x
\,\,\,\stackrel{x^{2}\ \mapsto\ x}{=}\,\,\,
{1 \over 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{x^{n/2 - 1} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x
\end{align}
with $\ds{0 < \Re\pars{n} < 2}$. Note that $\ds{{1 \over 1 + x} = \sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{\pars{-x}^{k}} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}\color{red}{\Gamma\pars{k + 1}}\,
{\pars{-x}^{k} \over k!}}$. With
[Ramanujan's Master Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RamanujansMasterTheorem.html):
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\tan^{n - 1}\pars{x}\,\dd x} =
{1 \over 2}\,\Gamma\pars{n \over 2}\color{red}{\Gamma\pars{-\,{n \over 2} + 1}} =
{1 \over 2}\,{\pi \over \sin\pars{\pi n/2}} =
\bbx{{\pi \over 2}\csc\pars{\pi n \over 2}} \\ &
\end{align}